# Is there a replace for "Tab"?

Tags: windows, microsoft-word, keyboard-shortcuts

My tab key has broken. I'm due to get a replacement, but is there any key combinations I can use in the mean time instead as I'm in the middle of writing a report.

Sorry, I should have specified, that I am using word, not any sort of terminal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Microsoft Office Word and want to indent rather than insert a horizontal tab character, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> works. If you want to insert a horizontal tab, copying and pasting works, otherwise there's the "Alt Code" method as supplied by Patrick.

For indentation there is also a toolbar button on all versions of Word (screenshot 2010):

[[image: Screenshot of indent and unindent buttons]
<sup>Click for full size</sup>](https://i.stack.imgur.com/irblB.png)

Answer (score 6):

Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> instead of <kbd>Tab</kbd>

For interest: See [ancient table](http://www.bbdsoft.com/ascii.html) of [ASCII control characters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_character#In_ASCII) etc.

```
Dec Hex     ASCII                           Key
0   00      NUL (null)                      ctrl @
1   01      SOH (start of heading)          ctrl A
2   02      STX (start of text)             ctrl B
3   03      ETX (end of text)               ctrl C
4   04      EOT (end of transmission)       ctrl D
5   05      ENQ (enquiry)                   ctrl E
6   06      ACK (acknowledge)               ctrl F
7   07      BEL (bell)                      ctrl G
8   08      BS (backspace)                  ctrl H   <-------
9   09      HT (horizontal tab)             ctrl I   <=======
10  0A      LF (line feed)                  ctrl J
11  0B      VT (vertical tab)               ctrl K
12  0C      FF (form feed)                  ctrl L
13  0D      CR (carriage return)            ctrl M   <------- (Enter)
14  0E      SO (shift out)                  ctrl N
15  0F      SI (shift in)                   ctrl O
16  10      DLE (data link escape)          ctrl P
17  11      DC1 (device control 1)          ctrl Q
18  12      DC2 (device control 2)          ctrl R
19  13      DC3 (device control 3)          ctrl S
20  14      DC4 (device control 4)          ctrl T
21  15      NAK (negative acknowledge)      ctrl U
22  16      SYN (synchronous idle)          ctrl V
23  17      ETB (end of transmission block) ctrl W
24  18      CAN (cancel)                    ctrl X
25  19      EM (end of medium)              ctrl Y
26  1A      SUB (substitute)                ctrl Z
27  1B      ESC (escape)                    ctrl [   <-------
28  1C      FS (file separator)             ctrl \
29  1D      GS (group separator)            ctrl [
30  1E      RS (record separator)           ctrl ^
31  1F      US (unit separator)             ctrl _
32  20      SP (space)                                
33  21      !       
34  22      "       
35  23      #       
36  24      $
```

etc

If anything after SP (your space bar) breaks, ask about Alt codes.

If your control key breaks, you may have to save up $10 for a new keyboard.

Answer (score 2):

You can hold down the Alt key and type 09 on your numeric keypad.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a tool that changes your key bindings (or even hacking at the registry) and change another key (I suggest Caps Lock) to work as a tab. I'd suggest looking at a [page on AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/misc/Remap.htm#registry) explaining how to do that (it also has information on how to do it with AutoHotKey; see below); it's too involved to list here.

Another option is [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com/); it's not as efficient as the above method, but AutoHotKey also allows much more advanced changes (binding a key to a key-combo, auto-replacing entered text, launching a specified program with a keyboard shortcut, binding gamepads to mouse & keyboard inputs, etc). You can also turn the change on and off easily, so if you're in a situation, say, where you need your Caps Lock more than your Tab key, you can just close the AutoHotKey script. The script for this would just be:

```
CapsLock::Tab
```

Just save that as a text file with .ahk extension and double click to run it (after installing AHK, assuming you allowed it to associate with .ahk files). You can even compile it to a standalone (and portable) executable.